# Node js vs Kotlin for REST APIs

Tags: node.js, express, kotlin, backend

Kotlin vs Node JS for REST Api's 
I couldn't find any proper explanation regarding the differences b/w Kotlin and Node JS for REST APIs
Which is better in performance wise?

Answer (score 13):

Let me set the context. Its Kotlin/JVM vs JS/Node.js. We cannot blindly say that this language is better. In general Kotlin is supposed to be faster since it compiled language compared to JS which is interpreted language.

Irrespective of the language used, we will discuss on the API architecture. Serving the APIs can be implemented in either blocking or non-blocking way (I am not going to explain about what it is). Traditionally before a few of years Java/Kotlin with Spring have been using the blocking architecture which delivered performance X. On a contrary, Node.js is based on non-blocking architecture which gave us better performance than the blocking architecture and architecture style is the only reason why Node.js performed better. Later Spring released a newer version of the framework to support non-blocking architecture. The non-blocking style is called as Reactive programming/Spring Webflux.

So now both of the languages support non-blocking architecture. In terms of raw language performance, Kotlin will be better since its compiled language. Also in theory interpreted languages are supposed to be slower. But we cannot say which is better without any testing.

Personally I am fan of Java/Spring because of OOPS and later at one point I started using TS/Node.js. TS eliminates most of the runtime issues with its type checking. But still we cannot compare it with the type system available in Java/Kotlin. As a language I feel Java/Kotlin is superior and one thing I like most in JavaScript is handling objects/JSON. Checkout "Kotlin for JavaScript﻿" as well which lets you write in Kotlin and transpile to JS. Ignore this "Kotlin for JavaScript﻿" feature, I am planning to try Kotlin/Spring in non-blocking architecture for my future projects. If you have usecases with WebSockets, I think Node.js will perform better and I am not sure If there are any libraries in Java/Kotlin since I havn't explored it.

One disadvantage in non-blocking style is that I need to pass the login context object to almost all the methods in the project. In blocking architecture we will add the login context information in thread local so that we can access it anywhere until the request is completed.

I am sure that I did not answer your question completely. But I hope that the information what I have give is useful.

Correct me If I am wrong in any of the aspects.